# Line break in JEXL String

Tags: java, jexl

I'm using JEXL in Java in standard way:

```
var script = new JexlBuilder().create().createScript(jexlScript);
var jexlContext = new MapContext(); 
var returnString = (String) script.execute(jexlContext));
```

Let's say that jexScript looks like:

```
var paramA = 'AAAA';
var paramB = 'BBBB';
var command = paramA + '\n' + paramB;
return command;
```

Output is:

```
AAAA\nBBBB
```

My question is: How to introduce **new line** char to properly format this text? Or any other way to get new line separation in String creating in Jexl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new to Apache JEXL, but I've found these ways:

#### 1. Use multi-line strings

```
var paramA = 'AAAA';
var paramB = 'BBBB';
var command = `${paramA}
${paramB}`;
return command;
```

The literal newline in the multi-line string format (delimited with backticks) will be preserved.  Use variable substitution to bring in your other variables.

#### 2. Use the context to inject newline as a variable

In your Java code, populate the context:

```
var jexlContext = new MapContext(); 
jexlContext.set("newline", "\n");
```

Then use it in your script:

```
var paramA = 'AAAA';
var paramB = 'BBBB';
var command = paramA + newline + paramB;
return command;
```

#### 3. Use Java-style Unicode escapes

This is a feature that existed but was undocumented prior to version 3.2 ([JEXL-331](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JEXL-331)).  You can use a Java-style Unicode escape inside a string literal.  The hexadecimal value of `\n` is 0x0a, so use:

```
var command = paramA + '\u000a' + paramB;
```